# When calling a function, is it possible to append a number or a character to the name of the function being called?

Tags: c++

So I have multiple functions that otherwise have same names but each just has a different number at the end of the function name like so:

```
void bark0() {
    cout << "A small amount of dogs are barking" << endl;
}

void bark1() {
    cout << "Some dogs are barking" << endl;
}

void bark2() {
    cout << "Bark Bark!" << endl;
}
```

Is it possible to call all of them from a for loop so that **int i** would be the current function to call?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // Call bark + i at the end || For example bark2(); when i == 2
}
```

Or is it possible to call a function that ends in the number that the user enters?

```
int input;
cin >> input;

bark+input();
```

I know that you can use a map of pointers to the functions, but I was wondering if there is a way of calling a function like this.

**EDIT**: I don't want to use parameters because the functions are supposed to be doing entirely different things. These barks 0, 1 and 2 were just examples.

Comment: Why do functions have parameters?

Comment: What you're describing is called "reflection" and is not supported in C++.  The best work around I am aware of is what you described.  A map of strings to function pointers

Comment: Not sure why people have been down voting the question.  It's not possible to do it in C++. but there are plenty of languages where it *is* possible - as such, I don't think it's an unreasonable question.

Comment: "the functions are supposed to be doing entirely different things" — then __name them accordingly__, not something0, something1 and something2. What about asking about the __actual problem__ you're trying to solve instead of asking how to implement a fundamentally wrong solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this in C/C++ because the name of the function is not part of the machine code after compiling.

I would approach this by creating an array of function pointers then calling the indexed function pointer in your loop.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers already explain that it is impossible the way you say. But noone prevents you from doing something like that manually:

```
using func_type = std::function<void()>;

func_type functions[3] = { &bark0, &bark1, &bark2 };

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) functions[i]();
```

Comment: ... and this is usually the best way of doing it even in c# and python (both of which do have powerful reflection capabilities).

Comment: Other answers explained this really well and what you posted fits my needs perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the pros and cons of using std::function here as opposed to a function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You could store your functions as functors or lambdas in a hash map that uses ints as keys, and loop over them that way, or an array instead of map.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a parameter for your function instead of this way :

```
void bark(int index) {
    cout << "Dog " << index << " is barking" << endl;
}
```

then

```
int input;
cin >> input;

bark(input);
```

and for your comment :

> I want these functions to do entirely different things

there is no problem, you can also use **switch** or **if** to separate works

```
void bark(int index) {
    switch(index){
        case 1:
            // ....
        break;
        case 2:
            // ....
        break;
        case 3:
            // ....
        break;
}
```

please read [this doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/) (see tables in the end of page )

Comment: I'm sorry for being unspecific, I want these functions to do entirely different things, so using the parameters won't help. I changed the printing statements inside the functions so it's clearer what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot call a function based on a name that is determined at runtime. Such thing could be possible in a language that supports reflection, but c++ is not such language.

What you could do in your simple example is to use the number as a function argument like Arash Hawaii suggested.

> the functions are supposed to be doing entirely different things

In that case the argument is not a good idea. A better option is to use an array of function pointers. Use the integer input as an index to the array. And be sure to validate the input!